# Dockerize a non-Maven JEE application

Tags: docker, jakarta-ee

I'm learning Docker by myself. I made it work and now I'm trying to Dockerize Java EE application. I've learned that we can Dockerize a Maven Java EE app and I've found how.

Is it possible to Dockerize a non-maven Java EE app? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run any build automator on your container, Maven, Ant ... so yes you can. How did you manage the deployment of you app ?

Comment: I don't use any build automator. How to dockerize a simple java application?